# How can I Add/Remove TPL Threads dynamically?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I have a process that looks at a database table, picks up records and sends emails. At different times of the day/month this process can get pretty backed up, and current we have 30 instances of a windows service running to keep up with demand.

We tried creating a single instance, and spinning up 6 long running TPL tasks per instance, but this is static and didn't scale well.

What I would like to be able to do is look at the table to be processed, count the number of requests, and add threads to a pool up to a specified cap, say NumProcessors * 10.  When the demand goes back down, pull these threads back out of the pool because each thread his the DB every 2 seconds, and I would much rather have 6 threads doing that per instance than 60.

Add threads is pretty easy, but I'm having a hard time thinking of a way to gracefully pull threads out of the pool as demand goes down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to have a *single* thread that reads from the database and sends the requests to processing threads (possibly using something like `ConcurrentQueue`).

This way, you always hit the database only once every 2 seconds (or whatever), but you also can have many threads that actually do the work that takes a long time (sending emails).

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scene `Task` use `ThreadPool` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx

You can control the max/min number of threads in the pool using `SetMaxThreads` and `SetMinThreads` functions.

So during peak time you can set `max threads` to `NumProcessors * 10`, and then when demand go back restore it to its previous value.